# Javascript size of a form object

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, dom-events

I have a very critical issue.

Below is my jsp code:

```
<html:select property="city"   name="city"  onchange="javascript:checkCity(this);">                             
                        <html:option value="N">NewYork</html:option>                      
                        <html:option value="F">France</html:option>
                        <html:option value="I">Italy</html:option>
                        <html:option value="P">Paris</html:option>
</html:select>
```

There can be single or multiple html select since my `<html:select>` is placed in for loop.

Below is my Javascript code:

```
var citySelected = new Array();
function checkCity(selObject)
{
     var form = document.forms[0];
     var cityObj =  form["city"];
     var len = cityObj.length;
     if(selObject==cityObj)      // if there is single <html:select> selObject is same as city Object.so this logic works fine
     {
        if(cityObj.value==cityObj.options[3].value)
        {
        alert("You have selected Paris City");
        citySelected[0] = true;
        }
        if(!cityObj.options[3].selected && cityObj[0])
        {
        var result = confirm("You have selected cities other than paris");
        if(result)
        {
            citySelected[0] = false;
        }
        else
        {
            cityObj.options[cityObj.options.selectedIndex].selected=false;
            cityObj.options[3].selected=true;
        }
        }
     }
     else{
         for(var i=0; i<len; i++) {  //if there are multiple <html:select> then take length of form object n iterate
                if (selObject == cityObj[i] )  
                {
                    if(cityObj[i].value==cityObj[i].options[3].value) // if 3rd option is selected
                    {
                        alert("You have selected Paris City");
                        citySelected[i] = true;
                    }
                    if(!sctypeObj[i].options[3].selected && citySelected[i]) //if 3rd option is deselected
                    {
                        var result = confirm("You have selected cities other than paris");
                        if(result)
                        {
                            cityObj[i] = false;
                        }
                    else
                    {
                        cityObj[i].options[cityObj[i].options.selectedIndex].selected=false;
                        cityObj[i].options[3].selected=true;
                    }
                    }
                }
         }
     }
}
```

Below is Javascript which works on jsp `onload()`:

```
function onload()
{
         var form = document.forms[0];
         var formObj =  form["city"];
         var size=formObj.size;
         var len = formObj.length;

         for(var i=0; i<len; i++) {
         citySelected[i] = false;
         }
         if(size==0){   //if there is seingle <html:select> element
            var cityvalue=formObj.value;
            if(cityvalue=="P")
             {
                 citySelected[0] = true;
             }
         }
         else
         {
            for(var i=0; i<len; i++) {   //if there are multiple <html:select> elements
             var cityvalue=formObj[i].value;
             if(cityvalue=="P")
             {
                 citySelected[i] = true;
             }
            }
         }
}
```

Here is where am finding problem. Onload if there is single or multiple `<html:select>` elements the logic works fine.But when there are no `<html:select>` elements at all in my jsp per say if I have option to delete all dropdowns then my jsp throws Javascript error:

> "size is null or not an object".

How do I resolve this? In `onload()` function I am differentiating between `<html:select>` element using size.

```
if(size==0)
{
   //logic for single <html:select>
}
else
{
  //logic for multiple html select
}
```

But when there are no `<html:select>` elements at all in my jsp per say if I have option to delete all dropdowns then my jsp throws Javascript error:

> "size is null or not an object".

How do I resolve this? Any help would be great..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternate way to determine the number of `<select>` elements within a form would be to use [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com)'s selectors like so:

```
$('#myForm select').length // returns number of <select> elements in the form
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fact that null/undefined evaluates to false in Javascript, like so:

```
if(!size)
{
   //logic for single <html:select>
}
else
{
  //logic for multiple html select
}
```

Comment: Also, since 0 evaluates to false, this code will still work even if you start getting a size of 0 at some point down the road.

Comment: nope that doesn't work.if there no html:select elements at all then its still throwimg error.for single select element size is 0

Answer (score 0):

The line `var size=formObj.size;` could be the cause of the problem. Try using an "or" statement to prevent the error when the size attribute is null or undefined:

```
var size = formObj.size || 0;
```

Comment: Yeah.the problem is in if(size==0) statement.i wnt to knw is there any other way to differentiate instead of using size of form object

Comment: Also the problem is var form = document.forms[0] in this statement.if there are no html:select elements at all its throwing errors

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
 var formObj = document.getElelementsByName('city');
 var length = formObj.length;

 if(length == 0) {
      // No select element
 }
 if(length == 1) {
      // One select element
 } else {
      // More than one select elements
 }
```

I am not sure how `size` will help here, this is not required. Size always will be returning `undefined` in this case.

Comment: I have tried with length already.The problem with it is if there are 4 <html:select> options /4 records then formObject length is 4 which is fine.But if there is 1 <html:select> option or 1 record then formObject returns length as 4(takes length of dropdown values) which causes ambiguity.however i have tried with property="city".will try be getElementByName("city").

Answer (score 0):

If for single `select` element `length` is returning 4, then it seems that other `select` elements present inside `jsp` with the same name and those are hidden.
However, `getElementByName('propertyName')` is not a correct function to iterate collection type, rather we need `getElementsByName('propertyName')`.

Comment: getElementByName('propertyname') was a typo

Comment: I have tried with getElementsByName('city').Strangely formObject length return 0 form multiple select elements.

Comment: However i found a quick fix as below.